# Why does the play mode and the build is different (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

On the Build, It looks like this:
[image: Build]

But on the Unity Editor, It looks Correctly:
[image: Unity Editor]

This is the material:

[image: Material]

Why does this happen?

Edit : It's maybe a particle system error, because the particles are different between editor and the build.

Comment: Try changing `Rendering Mode` from `Cutout` to `Opaque`.

Comment: That didn't work. It's now square decal. I originaly want to look like unity editor.

Comment: Also, check the build log for errors/warnings.

Comment: No errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to update your videocard driver but honestly I don't know if this is gonna work

In other games videocards driver or the videocard itself may be the problem